# Запись файла с содержимым кодом php [PHP]

Tags: php, файловая-система

Здравствуйте, при попытке записать PHP код в файл через file_put_contents. Ничего не происходит, спит 3 минуты и пишет TIME OUT. Проведя немного тестов я понял что достаточно символа `<?` чтобы повторилось подобное

Comment: Куда пишите? есть ли туда доступ на запись?

Comment: ``file_put_contents(__DIR__."/test.php","<?");`` права точно есть потому что удается записать файл с другим содержимым

Comment: у меня код выполняется на отлично. Никаких проблем не возникает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте бинарную запись в файл функцией

```php
file_put_contents('filename.php', $result, LOCK_EX);
```

Перед записью, вам необходимо будет **String** переменную с PHP кодом разбить на символы и упаковать **посимвольно** в цикле с помощью функции pack() в переменную **$result**.

Там, где используются не экранированные символы в PHP необходимо работать с бинарным их представлением. Функция pack() преобразовывает входящие данные в бинарный вид по шаблону. Подробней вы можете ознакомится в любом PHP справочнике.

P.S. С помощью функций pack() и unpack() можно также подружить любое сетевое приложение с PHP скриптом на пакетном уровне.

Comment: FILE_BINARY - это вы где такой флаг нашли?

Comment: Строку взял из первой же ссылки в поисковике исправив только название файла.

Comment: @Rootware, ``$code = "";
                            for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($downloadfiledata); $i++) {
                                $code .= pack("h*",$downloadfiledata[$i]);
                            }``получаю некое подобие PHP Кода. Отступы пропали. Что лучше брать для $format? http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pack.php

Comment: Точно все верно спасибо!